# OSX: check for subfolders, flatten directory structure into new folder, then move to desktop

Tags: macos, applescript

I am in the process of cleaning a huge library of mangas (mostly -but not only- image files). Each manga has a main folder containing subfolders, one for each volume.

But sometimes, volume folders contain only image files, and other times they contain subfolders.

**I'd like a script that would, for the selected manga folder:**

- check which volume folders have subfolders
- flatten the directory structure of the volume folders with
  subfolders. Rather than putting all images in the parent folder and
  erasing the subfolders, I'd like it to create a new folder on the
  desktop, and copy all the subfolders' images in it.
- rename the folder created on the desktop after its original parent
  folder

Before :

> manga_folder
>
> ```
> volume1_folder
>
>     subfolder1 / image1, image2, image3
>     subfolder2 / image4, image5, image6
>     subfolder3 / image7, image8, image9
>
> volume2_folder
>
>     image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9
>
> volume3_folder
>
>     subfolder1 / image1, image2, image3
>     subfolder2 / image4, image5, image6
>     subfolder3 / image7, image8, image9
> ```

After:

> Desktop:
>
> ```
> volume1_folder
>
>     image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9
>
> volume3_folder
>
>     image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9
> ```

**The original folders should stay untouched** so I can check for misplaced files etc.

Right now, I use an AppleScript that flatten the directory structure for each volume folder that I select. It creates a new folder inside, named after its parent folder with all the copied images inside.

What it does not:

- check which volume folders have subfolders (I have to select each
  volume folder individually and launch the script each time)
- move the created folder with flattenned directory structure to the
  Desktop

I did try to implement changes myself, but I could either move the new folder to the desktop or rename it after its parent folder. When I put the two instructions (whatever the one being put first), I would have an error saying that it couldn't find the folder after executing the first instruction. Here is the script :

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theTopFolder to (selection as alias)
    set theFiles to a reference to every file of (entire contents of folder theTopFolder)
    set theNewFolder to make new folder at theTopFolder with properties {name:"Flattened Files"}
    duplicate theFiles to theNewFolder
    set name of theNewFolder to name of theTopFolder
    
    
    --move theNewFolder to "Macintosh HD:Users:xx:Desktop:"
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Finder"
    repeat with f in (get folders of (POSIX file "/Users/username/manga_folder" as alias))
        make new folder at desktop with properties {name:(get name of f)}
        duplicate files of entire contents of f to result
    end repeat
end tell
```

You could also use a shell command like this:

`cd ~/manga_folder;for d in *;do mkdir ~/Desktop/"$d";find "$d" -type f|while read f;do cp "$f" ~/Desktop/"$d";done;done`

Or if you have GNU cp:

`cd ~/manga_folder;for d in *;do mkdir ~/Desktop/"$d";find "$d" -type f -exec gcp -t ~/Desktop/"$d" {} +;done`

Comment: Thank You. The AppleScript code did work, but it unecessarily copied all the folders on the desktop. Can it choose to copy only the folders that need to be flattened? I'd like the script to work on the currently selected folder as well if possible, like in my previous script. It's easier to manage that way.